# Can't capture match in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having a problem with capture groups in regex in javascript

I have strings such as `p4124`, `p74354`, `p10`, etc... which I want to extract the numbers only.

my regex is `/^p(\d+)/g`

if I do

```
str = p4124
str.match(patt)
```

I get `["p4124"]`

How can I get the captured match (to return 4124)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `g` flag from your regex and you will get the normal matches returned.

The `g` flag is used in this context for repeated calls on the same regex which is not what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

if the pattern is going to be the same (get rid of all non numbers), then you could use the following:

```
    var thestring = "p123";
    var thenum = thestring.replace(/^\D+/g, '');
    alert(thenum);
```

Let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the different capture groups with that:

```
var str = "p4124";
alert(/^p(\d+)/.exec(str));
```

first: the whole pattern

second: the capture group